# chatBot conversations challenge, is my code inefficient? Failing hidden test cases

Tags: java, performance, chatbot

Edit: This is a code challenge. I actually just ran it again and it was more specific that the code is innificient. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulIWq.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEExD.png).

I can't figure out what exactly is wrong with my code. It passes all the visible test cases but fails 4/5 the hidden test cases.

The challenge is to try to predict the next words of a given conversation (`currentConversation`) using a history of previous conversations (`conversations`). If a historical conversation has words matching the `currentConversation`, append the rest of the historical conversation to the `currentConversation`.

This is my code in Java:

```
public String[] chatBot(String[][] conversations, String[] currentConversation) {
    int hmNumOfMatches = 0; // highest matched conversation's similar words to the current conversation
    ArrayList<String> hmRestOfWords = new ArrayList<>(); // the rest of the words in the matched conversation

    // for all given conversations
    for (String[] pc : conversations) {
        int numOfMatches = 0;
        int indexOfLastMatchingWord = -1;
        HashSet<String> uw = new HashSet<String>(); // stores the unique words in pc (possible conversation)

        // for all words of possible conversation
        for (int j = 0; j < pc.length; j++) {
            String pw = pc[j]; // possible word

            // exclude words that have already been accounted for
            if (!uw.contains(pw)) {

                // for all words in the current conversation
                for (int i = 0; i < currentConversation.length; i++) {
                    String w = currentConversation[i];
                    if (w.compareTo(pw) == 0) {
                        numOfMatches++;
                        indexOfLastMatchingWord = j;
                    }
                }
                uw.add(pw);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<String> restOfWords = new ArrayList<>();

        // if there were matching words
        if (indexOfLastMatchingWord != -1)
            restOfWords = getRestOfWords(pc, indexOfLastMatchingWord);
        else continue;

        // set the highest number of matches if it has none
        if (hmNumOfMatches == 0) {
            hmNumOfMatches = numOfMatches;
            hmRestOfWords.addAll(restOfWords);
        }

        // also update it if it's less then the current number of matches
        if (hmNumOfMatches < numOfMatches) {
            hmNumOfMatches = numOfMatches;
            hmRestOfWords = restOfWords;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Create the answer
     */
    String[] answer = new String[currentConversation.length + hmRestOfWords.size()];

    int i;

    // append the current conversation to the answer
    for (i = 0; i < currentConversation.length; i++) {
        answer[i] = currentConversation[i];
    }

    // and append the rest of the words from the matched historical conversation
    for (int j = 0; j < hmRestOfWords.size(); j++) {
        answer[i + j] = hmRestOfWords.get(j);
    }
    return answer;
}

public ArrayList<String> getRestOfWords(String[] pc, int indexOfLastMatchingWord) {
    ArrayList<String> restOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = indexOfLastMatchingWord + 1; i < pc.length; i++) {
        if (!restOfWords.contains(pc[i])) restOfWords.add(pc[i]);
    }
    return restOfWords;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 4/5 *hidden* tests? Is this a code challenge or something? Why are those tests hidden/What are they testing for?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is. Editing my post.

Comment: It seems your impl takes too long. Have you already looked for areas you could optimize? May wanna decompose this into unit, then benchmark the units to see where the most time is taken.